# I need to write a program for my class will keep score of a bowling game

Tags: php, arrays

I need to write a PHP program that will keep score of a bowling game. I can handle the calculation of the scores that is not the problem. My problem is getting the data into arrays in the first place.

My idea is to have an array for each player like below:

```
$scores = array(
array(
    'name' => 'Player 1',
    'sheet' => '10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10'
),
array(
    'name' => 'Player 2',
    'sheet' => '10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10'
),
```

);

I wanted to have an initial form where you can enter the player names, this then creates the arrays and afterwards create another form for each player (array) to enter the scores.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Thanks

Edit: Will this work?

```
<input maxlength="30" name="players[1][player1]" size="30" type="text" />
<input maxlength="30" name="players[2][player2]" size="30" type="text" />
```

So the first form as show above will create the arrays and the the player name value. The second form like the below would add the scores, although I cant seem to get this to work.

```
<input maxlength="30" name="players[1][score]" size="30" type="text" />
<input maxlength="30" name="players[2][score]" size="30" type="text" />
```

Comment: You will need some sort of persistence such as sessions, a file scheme, or a database.

Comment: Im not sure how sessions would solve this, could you explain? I have eddied the question to show a possible solution to see if that would work.

Comment: Its not clear if you want to calculate the score at the end of the game after all the frames are known or if you want to calculate a running score after each frame.

Comment: Apologies i will calculate the score at the end of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example. Perhaps buggy but it should work (for inspiration)

```
<h1>Bowling</h1>

<?php

if ( isset ( $_POST['next'] ) ) {

  if ( isset ( $_POST['players'] ) ) {

    $exp = explode("\n", trim($_POST['players']));
    echo "<h2>Input Score</h2>";

    echo '<form method="post" action="bowling.php">';
    foreach ( $exp as $p ) {
    if ( trim($p) != '') {
      $name = trim(htmlspecialchars($p));
      echo '<fieldset>';
      echo '<label><h3>Input "' .$name.'" score</h3></label>';
      echo '<input style="width:100%" type="text" name="score[]" placeholder="Put in the score for ' . $name . '. Just for example 1 2 3 4 5">';
      echo '<input type="hidden" name="player[]" value="'.$name.'">';

      echo '</fieldset>';
    }
    }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="next" value="Results">';
    echo '</form>';
  }

  if ( isset($_POST['score'], $_POST['player']) ) {
    echo "<h2>Results</h2>";
    $i = 0;
    $result = [];
    foreach ( $_POST['player'] as $name ) {
      $result[$name] = $_POST['score'][$i];
      $i++;
    }

    var_dump($result);
  }


} else {
?>
<form method="post" action="bowling.php">
<textarea style="width:500px; height:500px;" name="players" placeholder="One player in each line and everything will be fine"></textarea>
<input name="next" type="submit">
</form>
<?php
} ?>
```

Comment: needs some persistent storage

Comment: Thank you bastey. I like what you have done. I tried to modify it so, that you enter in the score for each player when they bowl press submit then the form appears again, you enter in the next form and so on so it keeps updating the array until they have had their goes. But i cant seem to get it working. do you know how I could do this? I just want the form to loop really and keep updating the array

Comment: Just combine both parts and loop it all the time until the game is finished (add another input-field for it).